# Sample covariance between a quantitative variable and a binary encoded variable

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data

I have the following question: What does the sample covariance between a quantitative variable and a binary encoded variable tells us? And would it make sense to include the binary variable in a sample covariance matrix, given that we have multiple quantitative variables?